# When editing HTML in Sublime Text autocomplete <img> path

Tags: html, css, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Does sublime text3 has file path prompt?

for example :

```
<img> tag

src="img/apple/pic.jpg"
```

after img/ it can automatic prompt

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the features of a piece of software, not a specific programming problem

Comment: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AutoFileName just browse the plugin registry...

Comment: @Bojangles ***"unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."*** This question would be on-topic if it involved a feature of Visual Studio, why not Sublime?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text does not come with these features preinstalled. However, it's very likely that a plugin [such as this one](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AutoFileName) (I haven't tried it) will solve your issue. If it's an image you use like all the time, you can make it a snippet if you'd like so you could type *apic* for example, press tab, and it would expand. Otherwise, try the plugin.